# How do I define a constrained type in Swift?

Tags: swift

I keep bumping onto this problem repeatedly. In real life I see sets of numbers that represent a particular quality but I have difficulties to express them as distinct type in Swift.

For example the percent type. Let says I would want to have a Percent type with only integers. Also this percent would never be able to go over 100 or below zero.

I could express that in pure C as a union, with members ranging from 0 to 100. However using the Swift enum for that with underlying value type doesn't seem to me like to correct approach. Or is it?

Let's pick another one. Bribor Interbank Interest rate. I know it will always be a range between 0 and 20 percent. But the number itself will be a decimal with two decimal places.

What's the correct way to deal with this problem in Swift? Generics perhaps?

Comment: "I could express that in pure C as a union". Please show the code of that.

Comment: everything I can google up about "constraints" with types all involve Generics.  If this were my problem, I'd probably create my own class (e.g. "`BriborInterest`") where I would check and/or constrain the input in the init or setter for the object.  I.E. if the input isn't valid, throw an exception or return nil.

Answer (score 1):

As Michael says in the comment, probably something like this:

```
struct IntPercent {
  let value : Int8
  init?(_ v : Int) {
    guard v >= 0 && v <= 100 else { return nil }
    value = Int8(v)
  }
}
```

(Note: use a struct, not a class for a base value like that)

If you do that a lot, you can improve that a little using protocols, like so:

```
protocol RestrictedValue {
  associatedtype T : Comparable
  static var range : ( T, T ) { get }
  var value : T { set get }
  init() // hack to make it work
}

extension RestrictedValue {
  init?(v: T) {
    self.init()
    guard Self.range.0 <= v && Self.range.1 >= v else { return nil }
    value = v
  }
}

struct IntPercent : RestrictedValue {
  static var range = ( 0, 100 )
  var value : Int = 0
  init() {}
}
```

I don't think you can use Generics to limit base type values.

But I bet there is an even better solution - this one is definitely not awezome :-)

Answer (score 0):

Constraining the value of an object is not the same as a constrained type. Constraining values of numbers doesn't really make sense, as the things you are talking about are just numbers -- there is no such thing as a percent-number or a Bribor-Interbank-Interest-rate-number; they are just numbers. If you want to constrain their value, you do it wherever you get or use the numbers. It doesn't make sense to define a new type simply to constrain the values of an existing type.